# When I am using angular-cli, how do I implement the controller?

Tags: angular

What I want to do: simple event, when user clicks a button, "hello world" is output to console or screen

What I am having trouble with: I understand what a controller does, but what I don't understand is how to create a controller, link that file(if its a file) to my view. Do I just link the script src of the file? do i import it to component.ts?..this is where i am confused.

Comment: work through the tutorial on the site

Comment: @bryan60 link please?

Comment: https://angular.io/tutorial

Comment: @bryan60 i have tried this and it gives me no information on how to implement the controller

Comment: it definitely does. You're just searching for a specific term that isn't used in angular instead of actually working through it adn finding the angular equivalent of a controller.

Comment: ok maybe i missed something, let me try this again. thank you @bryan60

Comment: You don't create controllers in Angular. You create components and services. You associate a template (html) with a component. You will see how to do this in the above linked tutorial.

Answer (score -1):

In angular  component.ts file work as a controller.
The component is associated with view. If you are mapping from AngularJS to angular the component.ts is nothing but the controller of your view.